# XADES4J - How to change <ds:Object Id="xmldsig-1ddcf1ab-7648-4039-b166-69e14da39982-object0"...> to something other id

Tags: java, xades4j

When i signing XML document with Xades4J (Xades-BES), i'm getting signed document including my xml within something like:

`<ds:Object Encoding="UTF-8" Id="xmldsig-1ddcf1ab-7648-4039-b166-69e14da39982-object0" MimeType="text/xml">
 ....
</ds:Object>`

i must change `Id="xmldsig-1ddcf1ab-7648-4039-b166-69e14da39982-object0"` to `Id="Dokument-0"`

How can i do that ?

Thanks for all answers and sorry for my bad english.
Darek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there's no way to change how the signed data object id's are generated, mostly because the lib ensures that unique id's are used, even if a document contains multiple signatures.